# How to re-share a printer (adding extra queue?)

Tags: networking, printing

I would like to know if its possible and if so how one can (re-)share an already shared network printer in ubuntu?

I ask this because a host of mine can not print to one of my printers because of an unknown issue. Now I would like to "route" the printer connection from the problem-host over another host e.g. my Laptop to get it to the printer (my Laptop can print from said printer).

For this I guess it would be applicable to (re-)share the connection I have to the printer so that its available to the problem-host but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be informative and effective to determine and resolve the "unknown issue"?

Comment: The unknown issue has to do with an old version of CUPS which won't or isn't able to be updated and thus can't print properly. So it would be easier to give the print job to a CUPS that can print.

Comment: What version of CUPS are you running that "won't or can't" be updated?

Comment: Simply, open Control Center, right click on printer, check `Shared`. Shared printers are not re-shared by default. If it is an IPP printer you may need to enable`'Publish shared printers` in printer host.

Answer (score 0):

### share printer from ubuntu

run terminal

```
$ gksu nautilus
$ sudo wget http://prope.insa-lyon.fr/~ppollet/netware/ncpfs/contrib/ncp -p /usr/lib/cups/backend
```

then restart CUPS

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

the add a netware 
system => administration => printing 
chose the printer 
the type in URl

```
ncp://NETWARE_SERVERNAME/PRINTER_Q
```

### share printer from ubuntu to windows protocole

uneed to use samba

#### SAMBA installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install samba samba-common && sudo apt-get install python-glade2 && sudo apt-get install system-config-samba &&
```

/add a username

```
adduser username
```

/make password

```
passwd password
```

#### sharing the printer

go to **system => administration => printer**
click **New**
chose the sharing method 
then click on **browse** browse the printer & click Verify button to make sure that its working

 click **forward**

 & you may wanna take a look o this

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu
```

Comment: The printer is already shared from our server. I would like to reshare the printer, so that my or some Workstation acts as relay station for the Workstation that has the CUPS problem with printing directly.

Comment: @Lerkes You need to resolve the CUPS printing problem. All you would do by "re-sharing" is move the problem around. It won't solve it.